# how to get the name of the currently connected device to computer?

Tags: javascript

When I connect my phone to the computer and visit Google play store in google chrome, it seams like the page knows that the device is connected, like this picture:

[image: DeviceName]

How can I do it using JavaScript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can tell, once you link your phone to your Google account, Google attaches your phone's to your Google Play account and then displays it to you when you're looking at apps using your computer's web browser. Don't think there's any Javascript at play here.

Comment: google use ajax to fetch details of the device list, but it could be done without if they wanted to

Comment: Use AJAX to fetch details of your computer? I'd certainly hope no browser is revealing any sensitive information.

Answer (score 1):

You can't. The Google Play website doesn't know your phone is connected to your computer, it just knows which Android devices you've configured with you're Google account.